# Unable to Connect error with Zend_Rest_Client on localhost

Tags: php, zend-framework, localhost, zend-rest

I am using `Zend_Rest_Client` to connect `Zend_Rest_Server`, everything seems to be alright, but when I try to `get()` from the server I recieve this error:

> Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception:
>   Unable to Connect to
>   tcp://localhost:80. Error #10060: A
>   connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond.
>   in
>   C:\www\zf_1_72\library\Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Socket.php
>   on line 148

here is code, which I use

```
$client = new Zend_Rest_Client('http://localhost/my_application/api/index/');       
$client->auth($key);
$result = $client->get();
```

thank's for any advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This thread](http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-components-13/web-web-services-22/http_client-raising-error-10060-a-1302.html) suggetss the issue may be with the 'localhost' name - try using `127.0.0.1` instead.